# Solving Erratic Behavior with HttpWebrequest in SQL 2008 CLR UDF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, clr, user-defined-functions

We're currently attempting to implement a sql server 2008 udf to do expansion of shortened  urls.  We have it working quite well against most of the major url shortening services.     However, at seemingly random times it will "hang" and refuse to work against a certain domain (for example bit.ly) while subsequent calls to other services (for example tinyurl.com) will continue to succeed.

We initially thought this was due to some sort of blocking by the url shortening provider, but stopping and restarting the dbserver service cause subsequent requests to succeed.     Could it be that SQL server is somehow pooling outgoing http connections in some way?

Here's the code...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString UrlExpander(string url)
    {
            // Set up the Webrequest
            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            try
            {

            // Set autoredirect off so the redirected URL will not be loaded
            wr.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            // Get the response
            HttpWebResponse wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();

            return new SqlString(wresp.Headers["Location"].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            wr.Abort();
            throw ex;

        }


    }
};
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should not have a catch (Exception ex).  Instead, you should simply have wr.Abort() inside of a finally block.

Comment: yeah, that's true in most instances, but given the nature if this specific UDF, we don't really want an exception bubbling up into the TSQL level.  The rethrow in the code above was experimental to see if that would help the server recover.  In our mind, either it works, or it returns null.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing wresp.Close().

Answer (score 0):

Given the feedback from Jesse and our desire to have a function that returns either a properly expanded url or NULL, we have come up with the following which seems to process 1000s of minified URL with no further issues:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlString UrlExpander(string url)
{
    // Set up the Webrequest
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            // Set autoredirect off so the redirected URL will not be loaded
            wr.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            // Get the response
            HttpWebResponse wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
            wresp.Close();

            if (wresp != null)
                return new SqlString(wresp.Headers["Location"].ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (wr != null)
                wr.Abort();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return null;

}
```